# How to open a specific controller after user click on push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, pushviewcontroller

I'm trying to open a specific controller after the user click on a "new message" push notification, but I cannot find how to navigate to the conversation detail controller.

Here is my code in `didReceiveRemoteNotification()`

```
 var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController
 let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 var setViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("JSQVCTest") as! JSQVCTest
 setViewController.currentConversation = currentConversation
 rootViewController!.navigationController!.popToViewController(setViewController, animated: false)
```

When I run this, the app crash on the last line, because `rootViewController!.navigationController` is `nil`, and I get the message

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My storyboard looks like this:

1. Login as a View Controller
2. Navigation controller
3. conversation list as a tableViewController
4. conversation detail as tableViewController

EDIT: Ok now I manage to target all my controllers and print them in the log, however I can't present the one I want when the app return from the background:

```
var rootViewController = self.window!.rootViewController

let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

let navigationViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("navigationController") as! UINavigationController

var setConversationViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("conversationController") as! ConversationListTableViewController

navigationViewController.pushViewController(setConversationViewController, animated: false)

var setMessageViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("JSQVCTest") as! JSQVCTest

navigationViewController.pushViewController(setMessageViewController, animated: true)
```

Comment: Apart from you error, you're calling popToViewController. You can only pop-to something if its previously been pushed. Have you previously pushed the view controller you are trying to display?

Comment: @MrH and the `navigationController` is `nil`, which means nothing can even be pushed

Comment: I don't know, I'm just searching how to navigate to this specific controller by trying code that I found here and there, I'm new to swift and I can't find a proper tutorial to do that.

Comment: To understand navigation controllers etc. you can also read objective-c tutorials, its exactly the same principles. You don't necessarily need a navigation controller, it depends on your app design. Your view controller might be presented for example. Also you need to consider if the view controller you want to display is already displayed at the time the user clicks on a notification. I'd suggest getting some more background information on view controllers and navigation controllers in iOS in general first in order to understand what you need to do.

Comment: @Gruntcakes What kind of tutorial? I have read lots of them so far but I still don't see how to point to the specific controller I want. Do you have a link perhaps that could help me?